# Equation of bisector between two straight lines given in symmetrical form

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, 3d

Please help in solving the attached question.

I know in 2D, it is solved as
$\dfrac{ax+by+c}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}=\pm \dfrac{px+qy+s}{\sqrt{p^2+q^2}}$

Not sure if we use the same formula for 3D? And if yes, what’s the value of the constant c and s here?

[image]

Comment: Do you know how the 2D formulas are deduced from the definition of the bisector? Why similar principles should apply in 3D? Aside from that, you’re supposed on this site to use Latex to type mathematical symbols rather than linking images.

Comment: Not everybody knows how to do it. If somebody can edit it, will be helpful.

Comment: You’re here to learn, no? So you can have a look at [this tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) and you’ll be able to do it.

Comment: I have send an edit to your post. I hope you meant to write, $ax+by+c\sqrt{a sq+b sq}=\pm (px+qy+s\sqrt{p sq+q sq})$

Comment: Thanks much @user264745..I wanted this sqrt equation all under ax+by+c and likewise for the other…and asq means a^2 and likewise.

Comment: $(\sqrt{ax+by+c} )(a^2 + b^2) = \pm (\sqrt{px+ qy+s})(p^2 +q^2)$?, text: (\sqrt{ax+by+c} )(a^2 + b^2) = \pm (\sqrt{px+ qy+s})(p^2 +q^2)

Comment: Right, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In $3D$ the equation of the two lines is given as follows

$ \dfrac{ x - x_1}{a} = \dfrac{y - y_1}{b} = \dfrac{z - z_1}{c} $

for the first line, and

$ \dfrac{ x - x_1}{d} = \dfrac{y - y_1}{e} = \dfrac{z - z_1}{f} $

and these two symmetrical form equations correspond to the parametric equations

$P_1(t) = (x_1, y_1, z_1 ) + t (a,b,c) $

$P_2(t) = (x_1, y_1, z_1) + t (d, e, f) $

From here find the unit vectors

$u_1 = \dfrac{ (a,b,c) }{\sqrt{a^2 + b^2 + c^2} } = (a_1, b_1, c_1)$

$u_2 = \dfrac{(d,e,f) }{\sqrt{d^2 + e^2 + f^2}} = (d_1, e_1, f_1) $

The direction vectors along the two bisectors are

$ v_1 = u_1 + u_2 $  and $ v_2 = u_1 - u_2 $

And therefore, the symmetrical form equations of the two bisectors are

$ \dfrac{ x - x_1}{a_1 + d_1} = \dfrac{y - y_1}{b_1 + e_1} = \dfrac{z - z_1}{c_1 + f_1} $

$ \dfrac{ x - x_1}{a_1 - d_1} = \dfrac{y - y_1}{b_1 - e_1} = \dfrac{z - z_1}{c_1 - f_1} $

For the question quoted, $(x_1,y_1, z_1) = (3,-4, 5) $, $d_1 = (2,-1,-2) $, $d_2 = (4, -12, 3)$

From here $u_1 = \dfrac{ (2, -1, -2) }{\sqrt{2^2 + (-1)^2 + (-2)^2} } = (\dfrac{2}{3}, -\dfrac{1}{3}, - \dfrac{2}{3} ) $

and

$u_2 = \dfrac{ (4, -12, 3) }{\sqrt{4^2 + (-12)^2 + 3^2}} = (\dfrac{4}{13}, -\dfrac{12}{13}, \dfrac{3}{13} ) $

Hence,

$v_1 = u_1 + u_2 = ( \dfrac{38}{39} , -\dfrac{49}{39}, - \dfrac{17}{39} )$

$v_2 = u_1 - u_2 = ( \dfrac{14}{39} , \dfrac{23}{39} , -\dfrac{35}{39} )$

Normalizing $v_1, v_2$ by multiplying through by $39$, the equations of the bisectors are

$ \dfrac{ x - 3}{38} = \dfrac{y +4}{-49} = \dfrac{z - 5}{-17} $

and

$ \dfrac{ x - 3}{14} = \dfrac{y +4}{23} = \dfrac{z - 5}{-35} $

Comment: That is really helpful - thank you so much